# How to copy table with link to clipboard to paste it into excel

Tags: javascript, html, excel, clipboard

I create data on a website, which is table like. I want to copy that data to excel. I do that using Tabs to go to the next cell in the row and newlines to go to the next row:

```
let clipboard = 'My link' + "\t" + secondCell + "\t" + thirdCell + "\n" + 
firstCellSecondRow + "\t" + secondCellSecondRow + "\t" + thirdCellSecondRow;
navigator.clipboard.writeText(clipboard);
```

Copying that text into an excel table works well:

[image: Data in excel]

Now my challenge is, that I want to add a link to text of one cell. My intuitive approach was to add the following text to the clipboard:

```
let clipboard = '<a href="https://www.my-url.com">My link</a>' + "\t" + secondCell + "\t" + thirdCell + "\n" + 
firstCellSecondRow + "\t" + secondCellSecondRow + "\t" + thirdCellSecondRow;
navigator.clipboard.writeText(clipboard);
```

But that doesn't work, it will actually display the text with the html in it:

[image: Data in excel]

What I want is only the text "My link" and an actual link that is clickable:

[image: Data in excel]

Since copying of text with links is possible in excel, I feel that it should somehow work. Can I do that with javascript?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is how you achieve it in JavaScript:

```
let html = '<table><tr><td><a href="https://www.my-url.com">My link</a></td><td>secondCell</td></tr><tr><td>firstCellSecondRow</td><td>secondCellSecondRow</td></tr></table>';

const blob = new Blob([html], { type: "text/html" });

navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({ [blob.type]: blob })]);
```

I didn't write it as a snippet in the answer because StackOverflow has security limitations that disallows the clipboard in snippets.

If you try it in your console, this error may occur:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Document is not focused.

Here is a console-testable version of the code, it implies that you click on the page during the 3s timeout:

```
let html = '<table><tr><td><a href="https://www.my-url.com">My link</a></td><td>secondCell</td></tr><tr><td>firstCellSecondRow</td><td>secondCellSecondRow</td></tr></table>';

const blob = new Blob([html], { type: "text/html" });

setTimeout(() => navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({ [blob.type]: blob })]), 3000);
```

Result in Excel:

[image]

Comment: When writing this in a TS app, there are errors to note:
`Argument of type '{ [x: string]: Blob; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, ClipboardItemData>'.
  'string' index signatures are incompatible.
    Type 'Blob' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<ClipboardItemDataType>': then, catch, finally, [Symbol.toStringTag]ts(2345)`

Comment: @SebastianScholle it looks like TypeScript is happy with this code: `navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({ [blob.type]: Promise.resolve(blob) })]);` but it doesn't execute... Not sure why the definitions files don't match the actual implementation

Comment: @SebastianScholle the problem seems to have been fixed in the latest versions of TypeScript

Answer (score -1):

I found a really simple solution for your problem.

I first stored the linked text in another variable. Like this:

```
    let mylink = 'My link';
```

I then added the link to the variable as an  attribute.

```
    mylink.link = 'https://www.my-url.com';
```

I broke the variable into two parts, replacing the first part with our above variable. Like this:

```
    let clipboard = mylink + "\t" + secondCell + "\t" + thirdCell + "\n" + 
    firstCellSecondRow + "\t" + secondCellSecondRow + "\t" + thirdCellSecondRow;
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(clipboard);
```

Comment: I tested it out...it works perfectly. I am not saying mine is the only way...its just the simplest way.